# Drag and drop files to QListWidget created with QT-Designer

Tags: python, pyqt5, drag-and-drop, widget, mouseevent

i am trying to implement a drag and drop feature to PyQt5 QListWidget

it works if self.acceptDrops(True) is in the code but it works on whole application window and wherever i drag file in the window it will add a file to QListWidget...

My goal is to enable drag and drop only on QListWidget area. Please help me with some solution. Unfortunately i am stuck with this.

The Code is:

```
class okno_glowne(qtw.QWidget):

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.ui = Ui_main_new()
        self.ui.setupUi(self)
    
        #self.setAcceptDrops(True)

     def dragEnterEvent(self, event):
        if event.mimeData().hasUrls():
            event.accept()
            print("Coś się udaje")
        else:
            event.ignore()

    def dropEvent(self, event):

    
        if event.mimeData().hasFormat('application/x-qabstractitemmodeldatalist'):
            if event.source() == self.ui.lista_excele_drag:
                event.acceptProposedAction()
        for url in event.mimeData().urls():
             file_path = url.toLocalFile()
             self.ui.lista_excele_drag.addItem(file_path)

    def mousePressEvent(self, event):
        if event.button() == Qt.LeftButton:
             self.drag_start_position = event.pos()

    def mouseMoveEvent(self, event):
        if not (event.buttons() & Qt.LeftButton):
             return

        if (event.pos() - self.drag_start_position).manhattanLength() <QApplication.startDragDistance():
        return

        drag = QDrag(self)
         mime_data = QMimeData()
        mime_data.setText(self.ui.lista_excele_drag.currentItem().text())
        drag.setMimeData(mime_data)
        drag.exec_(Qt.CopyAction)

if __name__ == '__main__':
app =qtw.QApplication([])
Widget = okno_glowne()
Widget = QtWidgets.QStackedWidget()
w = okno_glowne()
w.show()
app.exec_()
```

Now the modified code with class in another file named mylistwidget.py

Okay , so i have done a research and i found out promoting widgets is easy ,but not as easy as to implement the code to work :D now , the dragEnter event works fine ( it is printing ) , but the rest as drop and mouse does not...

```
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *
from PyQt5.QtCore import Qt
from PyQt5.QtCore import Qt, QMimeData
from PyQt5.QtGui import QDrag

class MyListWidget(QListWidget):

# def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
#     QListWidget().__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        QListWidget().__init__(parent)
        self.setAcceptDrops(True)
    

    def dragEnterEvent(self, event):
        print("dragEnterEvent")
        if event.mimeData().hasUrls():
             event.accept()
        else:
             event.ignore()

    def dropEvent(self, event):
        print("dropEvent")
        if event.mimeData().hasUrls():
            for url in event.mimeData().urls():
                path = url.toLocalFile()
                item = QListWidgetItem(path)
                self.addItem(item)
            event.accept()
        else:
            event.ignore()

    def mousePressEvent(self, event):
        if event.button() == Qt.LeftButton:
            self.drag_start_position = event.pos()

    def mouseMoveEvent(self, event):
        if not (event.buttons() & Qt.LeftButton):
            return

        if (event.pos() - self.drag_start_position).manhattanLength() < QApplication.startDragDistance():
            return

        drag = QDrag(self)
        mime_data = QMimeData()
        mime_data.setText(self.currentItem().text())
        drag.setMimeData(mime_data)
        drag.exec_(Qt.CopyAction)
```

Comment: You need to override events in the widget that will eventually handle drag&drop events, not in the whole window. Since you're using a Designer UI, you will need to use a promoted widget for that QListWidget and implement the D&D event handlers in it. Do some research on how to create and use promoted widgets, there are various posts even here on SO. Note that classes and constants should always have capitalized names, while variable/function/method/attribute names should always start with a lowercase letter: please read the official [Style Guide for Python Code](//python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008)

Comment: Okay , so i have done a research and i found out promoting widgets is easy ,but not as easy as to implement the code to work :D

now , the dragEnter event works fine ( it is printing ) , but the rest as drop and mouse does not

i copied modified code in the task at the top

Comment: That's because you're setting the drag data as text, but your `dropEvent()` only checks for urls. What are you trying to achieve? Are you trying to *move* items?

Comment: I am trying to move excel file from local disc and drag to application to QListWidget and set  full path of this file as text to this QListWidget

Comment: I was referring to your `mouseMoveEvent` implementation. Note that you normally need to override `dragMoveEvent()` too.

Comment: I understand the assignment , but im stuck with implementation. No idea how to override... i was happy to see dragEvent working as first place but then stuck with no idea how to step further

Comment: Just override it in a similar way you did `dragEnterEvent`. I'd suggest you to take your time to read through the [drag and drop](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/dnd.html) documentation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay i got it...

To override drop function and initialize it i had to add new function:

```
def dragMoveEvent(self, event):
    if event.mimeData().hasUrls():
        event.setDropAction(Qt.CopyAction)
        event.accept()
    else:
        event.ignore()
```

Now it works like a charm.

Thanks for your contribution!